# Android - Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]

Tags: android, xml, localization

I have finished to write my small program and now I want to add locale.

Before I had next structure: **/res/value/strings.xml**

I have added to the structure new folder with file with another language:

**/res/value-uk/strings.xml** (it's ukrainian language)

after that I built my APK in AndroidStudio and I got error:

**Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]
Unknown failure (Failure)
Error while Installing APK**

I was searching this problem in google and nothing helped me.

Please reccomend me how to solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Please add the problematic xml file, as well as the manifest. Also, make sure you've places the `strings.xml` under values (and the respective Ukrainian folder) and not value folder.

Comment: try with a S: values-uk

Comment: @OriLentz, this is my [manifest file](http://pastebin.com/HRCkqPyR) and [strings.xml file](http://pastebin.com/TH1bHviJ)

Comment: whats the full error in the console logs ?

Comment: it is the full error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xliff namespace declaration in your strings.xml file seems to be wrong. Try using `<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">` instead. Or strip out all the `<xliff:g>` tags and see if it makes a difference - they are not needed any more after translation. And Chol is right: the default folder name for Ukrainian is `values-uk`, not `value-uk`.

Comment: thanks all works! I noticed this when began to translate not entire file at once but gradually words after words.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I found a lot of people managed to solve the problem by adding the full package name inside the various manifest "android:name".
It didn't work for me and I found out that my problem was different:

I had two string files, "strings.xml" and "strings-en.xml. In the former one I had some values with the field "translatable=false", such as:

```
<string name="db_name" translatable="false">my_db</string>
```

To solve the problem I had to REMOVE that string resource from the strings-en.xml, in order to have those strings only in the default strings.xml.

I hope this can help future developers.